# Does utils:::fixInNamespace make permanent changes? R

Tags: r, global-variables

I am using a 3rd party package for a script, I want to tweak one of the functions so that one of the variables created by the function is assigned to the global environment.

I did this previously by doing

```
fixInNamespace("the_function","the_namespace","namespace:::the_function")
```

And it opened a pop-up window where I could add my one line of code

```
assign("global_variable", "variable", envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

It worked like a charm, I could then write the rest of my script to use this newly formed variable.
I have tried to run the code again one day later and it can't find the global variable, and if I run

```
namespace:::the_function
```

It shows me the function code without my edit, why has it reverted back to its previous form? Is fixInNamespace not permanent?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not permanent.  It will last until the namespace is loaded again.  Normally namespaces stay loaded for an entire R session, so your change will last for the session.  (It is possible to unload a namespace without quitting R; in that case your change would be lost as soon as the namespace was unloaded.)  In any case, the next time the package is loaded, it will be the original version of the namespace.

There are a couple of ways to make your change permanent, but doing this is not a good idea.  One way is to call `assignInNamespace` from your startup code (see `?Startup` for possibilities).  Another is to edit the R source code, and build your own custom copy of R.

Neither of these is a good idea in the long term.  Some future version of R might change the function you've modified, and then you'll end up with a modified obsolete version.

Comment: Thanks, your answer really helped my understanding, I've requested some changes to the package, and in the meantime I've assigned an edited version of the function to the namespace.